# Unslider not working on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

This http://unslider.com/ for some reason is not appearing on my site, only the `li` text is showing and it is sliding but there is no appearance of the slider, just the text.

I have included the `js` files along with the css and markup but its somehow not showing me the full slider.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Webpage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "1style.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() {
            $('.banner').unslider();
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <br/>
    <h1 style="font-family:verdana; font-size:50px; font-weigth:bold; font-style:italic;" align="center" > Logo </h1>

    <div class="banner">
        <ul>
            <li>This is a slide.</li>
            <li>This is another slide.</li>
            <li>This is a final slide.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id = "footer">
        <div class = "container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "?">Terms of use</a></li>
                <li><a href = "?">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href = "?">Cookies</a></li>
                <li><a href = "?">Accessibility</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
.banner li { list-style: none; }
.banner ul li { float: left; }
```

Can someone check the link i provided above and tell me where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

---

Seems like none of the answers fix the problem at all, I guess i'll have to find a new slider.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why you dont add `http:` or `https:` in script src?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference really

Comment: @Mooseman - not sure if its working in all browsers

Comment: He deleted his comment, but he said something like you ... but I read somewhere safari has problem with this, but im rly not sure

Answer (score 4):

Unslider picks the height from first list item (`<li>`) from your list (`<ul>`). Hence to make it work perfectly fine just add the height to first element.

Answer (score 2):

Hey The problem is with the height of the container.

Because of the low height it isn't capable of displaying the overflow.

So i have made little changes to your code.

And they are :

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Webpage</title>
<style type = "text/css">
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; 
  background: #0f0; 
  min-height: 100px; }
.banner li { list-style: none; }
.banner ul li { float: left; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider();
});
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
<br/>
<h1 style="font-family:verdana; font-size:50px; font-weigth:bold; font-style:italic;" align="center" >Logo</h1>

<div class="banner">
<ul>
<li>This is a slide.</li>
<li>This is another slide.</li>
<li>This is a final slide.</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id = "footer">
    <div class = "container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "?">Terms of use</a></li>
            <li><a href = "?">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href = "?">Cookies</a></li>
            <li><a href = "?">Accessibility</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And It works for me !

Comment: Now its completely messed it up!

Comment: Checked your code in Firefox.

It tells ($) is not defined.

Means Jquery isn't working..

So add http:// and min-height parameters.

you can check the error(s) by using ctrl+shift+k in FF.

Answer (score 2):

Check my unslider.com help file:

```
        <!-- The HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Unslider.com example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $('.banner').unslider({
                speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
                delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
                complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
                keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
                dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
                fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
            });

            var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

            $('.prev').click(function() {
                unslider.data('unslider').prev();
            });

            $('.next').click(function() {
                unslider.data('unslider').next();
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

        * { 
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        }

        .banner {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            top: 50px;
            /*z-index: -1;*/

            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 24px;
            text-align: center;

            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

            background: #FFFFFF;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        }
        .banner ul {
            list-style: none;
            width: 300%;
        }
        .banner ul li {
            display: block;
            float: left;

            min-height: 500px;

            -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
            -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
            -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-size: 100% 100%;

            box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        }

        .banner .inner {
            padding: 360px 0 110px;

            float: left;
            vertical-align:-100px;
        }

        .banner h1, .banner h2 {
            font-size: 40px;
            line-height: 52px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .banner .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 25px 0 0;
            padding: 9px 22px 7px;
            clear: both;

            color: #fff;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            border : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) solid 2px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .banner .btn:hover {
            background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        }
        .banner .btn:active {
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
            -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
            -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
            -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
            filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
        }

        .banner .btn, .banner .dot {
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
            -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
            -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
            -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
            filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
        }

        .banner .dots {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .banner .dots li {
            display: inline-block;

            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            line-height: 10px;
            margin: 0 4px;

            text-indent: -999em;

            border: 2px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 6px;
            cursor: pointer;
            opacity: .4;

            -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
            -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
            transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
        }
        .banner .dots li.active {
            background: #fff;
            opacity: 1;
        }  

        .unslider-arrow {
            font-family: Expressway;
            font-size: 50px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #3d3d3d;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
            padding: 0 20px 5px 20px;
        }

        .next {
            position: absolute;
            top: 65%;
            right: 0  
        }

        .prev {
            position: absolute;
            top: 65%;
            right: 90 /* change to left:0; if u wanna have arrow on left side */ 
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <!-- Body of HTML document -->

    <body>
        <div class="slider">
        <div class="banner">
          <ul>
          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
              <p>smaller p text</p>

                <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
              <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
              </div>
              </li>

           <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
             <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
              <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
              </div>
          </li>

          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
          <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
              <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>


        </div>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">&larr;</a>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">&rarr;</a>
        </div>
   </body>  

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. Slider is created, but slides are outside the box and overflow is hidden so you don't see them. Add this css

```
.banner ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: No, I think the problem is that I have to create the design (css) myself, the actual function is working but there is no design, I thought it would be included

Comment: You have docu on that page unslider.com What styling do you mean? You want dots at the bottom? Use `$('.banner').unslider({ dots: true });` There is no more styling there. You have to design your slides "manually" because they are YOUR slides.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify dots:true in your javascript code, for example, apply this, and you will see it works fine.

Here is working jsfiddle link for you.

[LINK JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UmtkY/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider({
        speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
        delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
        complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
        keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
        dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
        fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
    });

});
```